# How to inject a single factory instance to multiple repositories and unit of work using ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

First, I have a dbcontext factory which is defined `public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory` and it just creates a context if one doesn't already exist.

Next, I have a generic repository that is defined `public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
where T : class` which takes the factory in the constructor.  I have other concrete repositories that inherit from this one.

I also have a unit of work class that is defined `public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork` which takes the factory in the constructor and saves all changes to the context inside the factory (which all repositories should be using).

In my controller, I have the constructor set as `public ProjectController(IDatabaseFactory factory, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IProjectRepository projectRep, IUserRepository userRep)`.

Basically, I need the same instance of the factory to be passed to the unit of work and all repositories.  With ninject, it creates a new factory for each object instead of passing a single instance to them all.  Is there a way to only allow the single instance to be passed via ninject or am I not creating my factory correctly and/or not understanding ninject correctly?

Here are my bindings in ninject:

```
kernel.Bind<IProjectRepository>().To<ProjectRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IIssueRepository>().To<IssueRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because by default `Ninject` uses the `Transient` scope - which creates a new instance every time a type is requested.

**More info:** https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

You should specify the scope depending on the actual usage of a particular instance of a type throughout your application:

Example could look like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Comment: Really?  I tried searching for that answer for the past hour and a half.  That is exactly what I was looking for.  I have no idea why it was so hard to find that answer through google.  Perhaps I was trying to make it much more difficult than it was.  Thanks again!

Comment: If you found my post useful you can accept it as an answer :)

Comment: I will - you answered it too quickly and now I have to wait 4 minutes :)  Thanks though.  Quick question if you have a second, if I put the factory as singleton - will it create a single instance application wide or only within the current controller?  If I want a different instance of the factory for IssueController than ProjectController (but a single instance of it within that specific controller), will ninject take care of that for me?

Comment: `Singleton Scope` will create only one instance throughout the entire application - so all controllers will receive exactly the same reference. If you want a different instance inside your controllers you should consider using either the `Request Scope` or the `Transient Scope` - please take into account that your controllers will be re-created for every request. You should play around with it and see what suits you best! :)

Comment: This is actually working perfectly in my application, so I won't need to change the scope from Singleton.  Again, thanks for your quick answer.